# Codeigniter only can access url under sub-folders of root

Tags: apache, codeigniter

I had a  website writed by codeigniter on VPS
2 days ago , i reinstall the OS and want to recovery the whole site.

I copy all the original settings .

i paste  vritaul host file as original.
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
and put the whole site's data in the same system path /home/www/MYSITE

However,it doesn't work.

i can sure it can correctly access the sub-path of the website
but can not access the website by base_url

you guys can try http://www.tao2tw.com/assets/images/VIP.jpg
and try http://www.tao2tw.com/

there is my problem....i have no idea...i restore with the full originally setting.

i didn't change the .htaccess file (kept it as before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't with the files, the problem is within the database.

Have you imported the database to your server? The name is the same? And the credentials? Check the config file database.php and see if everything matches

Comment: Ooops you solution fix my problem thanks!!!! but why ci didn't show any error....it's not so user-friendly for debugging.><

Comment: It showed to me, when I went to http://www.tao2tw.com/ an error saying that the database couldn't be loaded appeared

Comment: i thought my browser may cache the result? only return 500 error!